# UIButton action is not firing from my own class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class which is generating UIButtons dynamically and I want to keep the selector action in the same class as method to make it generic. When I click on the button it crashing. Bellow is my code

### RB_RadioButton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RB_RadioButton : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *options;
}

-(id)initWithOptions:(NSArray *)options;

-(void)renderRadioButtons:(UIView *)view initialXPos:(int)initialXPos initialYPos:(int)initialYPos height:(int)height width:(int)width spacing:(int)spacing;

@end
```

### RB_RadioButton.m

```
#import "RB_RadioButton.h"

@implementation RB_RadioButton {
    NSMutableArray *buttonArray;
}

-(id)initWithOptions:(NSArray *)optionsArray {
    if(self = [super init]){
        options = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:optionsArray];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)renderRadioButtons:(UIView *)view initialXPos:(int)initialXPos initialYPos:(int)initialYPos height:(int)height width:(int)width spacing:(int)spacing {
    buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int xpos = initialXPos, ypos = initialYPos;
    for (int i = 0; i < options.count; i++) {
        UIButton *radio = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, height, width)];
        radio.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [radio setTag:i];

        [radio addTarget:[RB_RadioButton class] action:@selector(actionTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xpos+30, ypos, height, width)];
        l.text = [options objectAtIndex:i];
        ypos = ypos + height + spacing;       
        [view addSubview:l];
        [view addSubview:radio];
    }
}
-(void)actionTap{
    NSLog(@"lll");
}

@end
```

### viewController.m

```
#import "RB_ViewController.h"
#import "RB_RadioButton.h"

@interface RB_ViewController ()

@end

@implementation RB_ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil];

    RB_RadioButton *rd = [[RB_RadioButton alloc]initWithOptions:arr];

    [rd renderRadioButtons:self.view initialXPos:20 initialYPos:20 height:20 width:20 spacing:10];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Above code is crashing without any message in debug console.

Please help !

Thanks

Comment: try like this         [radio addTarget:self action:@selector(actionTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: as a "target" for addTarget:... method you should pass OBJECT

Comment: Did you add an exception breakpoint to the project? If it's crashing then it should give you a crash log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you write this line of code it'l take class method so define `actionTap` as class method then it'l works like below.

```
[radio addTarget:[RB_RadioButton class] action:@selector(actionTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

+(void)actionTap{
    NSLog(@"lll");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is that:

```
[radio addTarget:[RB_RadioButton class] action:@selector(actionTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

`actionTap` is normal method which requires `self` pointer but you are trying to invoke it on `Class` object!

This line should look like this:

```
[radio addTarget: self action:@selector(actionTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

To make it work you have to fix also memory management. Controller should remember your `RB_RadioButton` object as a filed and release it in dealloc method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a",@"b",@"c", nil]; // here also you had a memory leak

    rd = [[RB_RadioButton alloc]initWithOptions:arr]; // rd is object field
    [rd renderRadioButtons:self.view initialXPos:20 initialYPos:20 height:20 width:20 spacing:10];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [rd release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```